# Force specific encryption cipher for S/MIME mails

Tags: encryption, email, cipher-selection, smime, enigmail

I have a number of contacts who can only decrypt 3DES, when it comes to S/MIME encrypted mails. I'm aware that this is by far not ideal, but better than no encryption at all.

My problem is, that I can't find a way to force Thunderbird to use 3DES for specific mails. Thunderbird itself doesn't seem to have an option, so I've installed the Enigmail plug-in, which states in the FAQ:

> Note that you can force usage of a specific symmetric algorithm by using the GnuPG option --cipher-algo, but this is not recommended; this option can easily break things and is intended for debug purposes only.

This sounds good, but the setting does not change a thing for me.

I've also asked on the [mozilla support page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1278624) and on the [enigmail support page](https://sourceforge.net/p/enigmail/forum/support/thread/41bec396f2/)

I'm baffled that there's no obvious solution to this.

How can I force Thunderbird to use a specific encryption cipher for S/MIME encrypted mails?

Comment: An email client should automatically recognize the ciphers supported by the other client from a signed email. However 3DES is very old and I know it is not supported any more for security reasons by some clients since years. Not sure about Thunderbird though. The latest S/MIME 4.0 RFC marks 3DES as historic.

Comment: That's correct. Replies usually work, but I frequently have to write new mails to such contacts.

Comment: Even for a new mail, in order to encrypt Tbird _must_ have and use the recipient's certificate -- which is _usually_ obtained from a prior email but can also come from other sources like LDAP -- and that certificate normally contains the recipient's capabilities. AIUI Tbird (like Firefox) uses its own cert store; look in there for the cert and look at its SMIMECapabilities extension.

Comment: While that sounds fantastic, it doesn't work. When I send a mail to said contacts it's encrypted using AES128, which they can not decrypt.

Comment: As a workaround, the recipient can setup a contact form, that encrypts the message for the recipient using S/MIME encryption with whatever ciphers the recipient supports, and sends the encrypted message to the recipient by email.  See https://www.encryptedcontactform.com/ for an example.

Comment: For what it's worth, Outlook does support choosing the cipher, including choosing 3DES (though it defaults to AES).

Comment: The fundamental question is always: What is the threat model you try to defend against? If the recipients are capable only of "historic" encryption, then it is not unlikely that their system (also) has other attackable weaknesses. As an alternative to message encryption, would enforced transport encryption be viable? Or sending an encrypted zip archive?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find out a little more about how and where Thunderbird stores the ciphers of the communication partner, but it looks like it's not actually stored with the user or his/her certificate. Therefore, Thunderbird uses a default cipher, probably as defined in the S/MIME RFC it implements. There seems to be no way for the user to set the default cipher.

The only way I can think of to make Thunderbird respect the other side's ciphers properly, is not to create new emails, but to always reply to an existing one.

Comment: Thank you for your input. You're right, replying to emails works fine, but that's not viable. I understand that the mail client/setup chooses a sane default cipher for the user, as most users don't know what would be a good choice, but I am perplexed that there is **no** option of specifying a certain cipher.

Comment: I completely understand that you do not find this viable. However, it looks like it is the only answer you can get (unless you contribute a solution to Thunderbird).